Gray Out "Name can be simplified"
For reasons unknown I recently had to reinstall Visual Studio on my laptop as it simply stopped worked.
In doing so my settings were reset. Prior to the reset the code relating to the warning "Name can be simplified" would always appear in grayscale providing an instant and obvious warning of this kind of "issue".

Previously when hovering over the grayscale text it would give the warning, now it appears as though it is normal code, although hovering over it will still give the warning. It just isn't obvious at a glance that the "issue" is there.
I am guessing Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors, but I can't find what it would be at all.
Any help would be appreciated.

There doesn't seem to be any mention of the text "Name can be simplified" in that screenshot, can you clarify what exactly it is that you're asking about?

There are various ways that IDE0001: Simplify name can be supressed. Check whether one or more of those has been applied?

@LasseV.Karlsen hopefully improved the question :)

@Damien_The_Unbeliever the warning triggers correctly both before and after the reinstall, I believe that is part of my main.ruleset in solution items, it is just the visual indicator that is missing.

Are you saying that the hover-gives-warning shows the warning for both lines, even though the first line of code looks like it is actually required?

They both give the warning when hovering, only when I could make it grayscale as was the case before there was absolutely no need to hover as it was obvious what the issue was.

Turns out that using the high contrast theme turns this off.
Any other theme the greyed out code returns.
